# "daran etwas" or "etwas daran"?

Tags: word-order

When using "daran etwas" I am wondering if the order ever makes a difference. This sentence was randomly selected from DWDS:

> Ja, fällt Ihnen **daran etwas** auf?

Is there a difference with:

> Ja, fällt Ihnen **etwas daran** auf?

Does the order of these ever make any difference?

Comment: Word order mainly impacts emphasis (together with stressing syllables or words in spoken language). In these examples the first word is emphasized more (in particular in the first example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a grammatical decision (both versions are correct in this regard) but rather one of emphasis and where to put it.

In many cases the word order in German is prescribed to a much lesser extent than it is in English. Perhaps the reason is that German has retained a richer flexion system and therefore the word order is not as important for expressing a certain meaning than it is in English. (Compare i.e the even less important word order in Latin, which has a flexion system even richer than German.)

That leaves worder order to express emphasis: put a word up front (or in some cases to the end) and you stress this word at the cost of the others:

> the green big house
> the big green house

one house is distinctively "green" first and foremost and happens to be big whereas the other house is big and this perhaps makes it stand out from a group of (also green) houses.

The same here. Here are possible contexts for your sentences:

> Ja, fällt Ihnen *daran* etwas auf?

This could be meant as "Do you notice something on *this*? Or *this*? Or maybe *that one*?"

> Ja, fällt Ihnen *etwas* daran auf?

"Do you notice *anything* on this? Take a close look!"

Comment: There is definitely a preference in English for "the big green house" over "the green big house", regardless of emphasis. I suppose people learning English as a second language have to learn the correct order of adjectives; a list is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Order). English tends to have specific word order preferences even cases where there is no grammatical difference, In German most of the word order rules are more like suggestions.

Comment: While what you say is true, RDBury, in the context of a conversation in which two people are talking about big houses the given word order could apply. "Of all the houses here, I like this big house." "But I like that big house." "Which big house is it you like?" "I like the green big-house." Possible...

Comment: @user44591: It's possible, but there's a strong preference. I'd probably use "The green one, " or "The green one in this group of big houses," if it wasn't clear which big houses were meant. A very strong emphasis would be needed to change the word order: "The GREEN big house." Not that this rule is totally inflexible, Wikipedia gives the example "big bad wolf", which (in my opinion) is unexplainable except as a fixed phrase. "A good little house" would be preferred over "a little good house".